# Finding the image of an element under an automorphism by GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

I am doing GAP to find the image of an element under an automorphism of a certain group:

```
a4:=Group((1,2,3),(1,2)(3,4));
e:=Elements(a4);
w:=Elements(AutomorphismGroup(a4));;
t:=AsGroupGeneralMappingByImages(w[2]);
Image(t,e[5]);
```

the answer is `(1,3,4)`. Am I on a right way? Thanks for your help, my friends.

Comment: It works OK, but if you want to compute with large finite groups then you should avoid using the function $\mathsf{Elements}$, because it will use up too much space.

Comment: Also, you do not need to call `AsGroupGeneralMappingByImages` (which just forces a certain internal representation), but can use immediately: `Image(w[2],e[5]);`